# Inner function taking arguments from outer

Tags: javascript

I don't get how the inner function gets passed the arguments from `.sort()` method. 
I know that `.sort()` passes the values to `createComparisonFunction()`, but how do they end up in the inner function? Does it just take any unused arguments from the outer function?

I'd like to understand that behavior.

```
    function createComparisonFunction(propertyName) {

        return function(object1, object2){
            var value1 = object1[propertyName];
            var value2 = object2[propertyName];

            if (value1 < value2){
                return -1;
            } else if (value1 > value2){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    var data = [{name: "Zachary", age: 28}, {name: "Nicholas", age: 29}];

    data.sort(createComparisonFunction("name"));
    alert(data[0].name);  //Nicholas

    data.sort(createComparisonFunction("age"));
    alert(data[0].name);  //Zachary
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: This is an anonymous function in JavaScript. `data` consists of two objects and the `propertyName` is passed into the createComparisonFunction.

Comment: The "technology" is called closure, more details on how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the `.sort()` function does *not* pass parameters to "createComparisonFunction". Instead, "createComparisonFunction" does exactly what its name suggests: it **creates** a function and returns it. The returned function is the one called repeatedly by the `.sort()` method.

Note that in the call to `.sort()`:

```
data.sort( createComparisonFunction("name") );
```

the "createComparisonFunction" is being **called**.  That's what the parenthesized argument list (with the single parameter `"name"`) means — **call this function**.  That happens before the runtime invokes the `.sort()` method.  What's passed to `.sort()` is the return value, which is itself a function.

The most interesting thing going on is that the returned function — which takes *two* parameters, as a sort comparator should — has access to the parameter originally passed to "createComparisonFunction". That's because a function that's returned from another function retains access to its original creation-time local variable context.

Comment: Now i get it, thanks. But why is the createComparisonFunction() function executed before sort()?

Comment: @user3271152 `sort()` function can't be executed unless all its arguments are known. So arguments like `createComparisonFunction("name")` are evaluted upfront.

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods call and apply.
For examplem, createComparisonFunction.apply(someNewContext, someArguments).
First argument for both methods should be context.

Comment: I don't think `.call` and `.apply` have anything to do with the question here, though of course it is true that they can be used.